# How can I compare columns of a dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a large array of data which I have read into a dask dataframe. This data frame has two columns that I believe to be redundant (i.e., have identical values).  These columns are string-valued -- they give the names of growth media used for incubating colonies of cells.

I would like to check my hypothesis that the two columns are identical before dropping one of them.

The simplest solution I could come up with was the following:

```
(df['growth_media_1'] == df['growth_media_2']).all().compute()
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.

+--------+---------+----------+
| Column | Found   | Expected |
+--------+---------+----------+
| input  | float64 | int64    |
| output | float64 | int64    |
+--------+---------+----------+

Usually this is due to dask's dtype inference failing, and
*may* be fixed by specifying dtypes manually by adding:

dtype={'input': 'float64',
       'output': 'float64'}
```

I thought this might be because there were some `NaN`'s in the columns, so I tried doing `.dropna()` before the comparison.  But that did not fix the problem.

After extensive flailing, I ended up with this arcane mess:

```
(df['growth_media_1'].dropna() == df['growth_media_2'].dropna()).astype('bool').all().compute()
```

but even *that* did not solve my problem.

The error message really isn't helpful, since neither `pd.read_csv` nor `pd.read_table` are involved, as far as I can tell. However, `pandas.read_text` is in the backtrace, so perhaps dask is writing files for different shards of the data.

(I'm using dask version 1.2.2, if that helps. I'm using this on a high performance cluster, which lags the bleeding edge of software.)

Comment: Have you tried `(df['growth_media_1'].compute() == df['growth_media_2'].compute()).all()` ? And if there is maybe a couple rows off, but you still consider it pretty much redundant, then use `(df['growth_media_1'].compute() == df['growth_media_2'].compute()).value_counts(normalize=True)` to see %match. I realize you would be calling `compute` on the two series, which may be memory-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have inconsistent types in your Dask dataframe.  Without looking at your data, it's hard to figure out what the problem is.  But you could probably do the following to coerce the types.

```
df[['growth_media_1', 'growth_media_2']] = df[['growth_media_1', 'growth_media_2']].astype('float64')
(df['growth_media_1'] == df['growth_media_2']).all().compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.

What I needed to do was to *initially* read the data with the `assume_missing=True` argument.  Like this:

```
df = dd.read_csv('r1c5va879uaex_r1c639xp952g4.csv', assume_missing=True)
```

After that, the simple

```
(df['growth_media_1'] == df['growth_media_2']).all().compute()
```

worked just fine.  I could not figure out how to repair the dtype assignment once the Dataframe had been loaded (using `astype()` didn't solve my problem).

The error message is almost comically misleading, because it tells me to fix the invocation of `pd.read_csv`, when it was `dask.dataframe.read_csv` that was the call I needed to repair.